# belongsTo relationship - Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel

When I use `$message->orders` it returns this data:

```
{"id":10,"order_id":0,"cust_id":1,"seller_id":1,"address_id":2,"product_id":170,"quantity":10"}
```

But if I try to return just the `id` like `$message->orders->id`, I get the following:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

**Code:**

```
   @foreach($conv_messages->messages as $message)
       {{ $message->user->name }}
                <p>{{ $message->body }}</p>


       <p>order id: {!!$message->orders-id!!} 

    @endforeach
```

Comment: When you say `$message->orders`, does it mean that a single message has multiple orders. If so, then you cannot use `$message->orders->id` as `$message->orders` will return a collection. Also, since your are getting the error `Trying to get property of non-object`, it means that `$message->orders` is returning `null` for one or more of the `$conv_messages->messages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
@foreach($conv_messages->messages as $message)
    {{ $message->user->name }}

         <p>{{ $message->body }}</p>

         <p>order id: {!!$message->orders['id']!!} 

    @endforeach
```

Comment: Perfect, i did it this way before but forgot how to, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If when you print `$message->orders` you get exactly what you said (an json string), so you obviously will not be able to access any property, since it's not a PHP Object anymore.

Something has converted your object to an JSON, or it was always an JSON.
If you need to access an JSON property, you must first decode it:

```
<?php $messageOrders = json_decode($message->orders) ?>

{!! $messageOrders->id !!}
```